# Share Projects, IDE (and possibly databases?) between computers

Tags: eclipse, repository, share, workspace

I often find myself working on two different computers in different places and i was wondering how to share as much as possible between these PCs with the least issues possible.
At the moment i'm using dropbox to share the projects i work most often on (2-3 projects, so no big deal) but my whole workspace is actually bigger than my dropbox space.
What i would like to do is to share all my projects, Eclipse and also the working environments (or at least the databases) and i was thinking to either use an USB hard drive or a repository to do this. There are a lot of issues i can think of about this and i'm pretty sure there are even more issues i haven't thought of:

- First of all i know one day i'll forget the hard drive home when going to work and i'll screw up a job day by going back and forth between home and my office so using the repository sounds like a better idea
- How bad can be to share database and IDE files? Though my computers run Windows 7 and 8 and both have a 64bit architecture i reckon that sharing such things might lead to bad behavior or things simply not working (for example if somehow one my PCs will assign a different drive letter to it things might not work and i'll have to manually assign it, leading to a waste of time).
  Also using a repository for this might not be ideal since it might create a lot of useless versions. I'd love to not have to configure and upgrade each IDE separately and to not update databases manually but i can live without this feature as long as i can share my projects
- In case i use an USB hard drive and put even Eclipse and the databases in it, how bad it could be performance-wise? I'm pretty sure using an USB drive will affect performances a lot
- A lot of the projects i work on already use a repository, I have projects using Git, SVN and Mercurial. Should i use one of these to share all my projects how will interfere with already existing repository information?
- Am i right in thinking that sharing a whole Eclipse workspace (so including will cause issues if the paths between the 2 computers are different? I might have to set thing up differently for each PC (for example if i use external programs and libraries, such as Android SDK, they might be in different places)

And i'm sure there will be more on this. So, my questions are:
1) Is it possible to share IDE and databases (that is, without using periodic import/export) between two PCs without issues or is it better to just share workspaces or even just single projects?
2) Taking into account the issues above, what's the best strategy to share files? I can accept different ways to share files than the two i thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have an identical IDE installed on computers (All the configuration should be the same, you can configure your Eclipse and zip the Eclipse files copy it on another computer then you have an identical IDE) also using maven as build tool makes it easier for you to share project between IDEs (on paper, you even don't need same IDEs) and for the workspace i guess the best solution would be a source control system,having share folders/usb drives can easily end up in mess.